# Compare, find and delete elements from numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, set

I have two numpy arrays as follows:

```
text = [one.csv , two.csv, three.csv]
result = [one.csv, two.csv, three.csv, four.csv, five.csv]
```

How can I find similar elements in both of the numpy arrays and deletes them? So that my result array will only have

```
result = [four.csv, five.csv]
```

Comment: What exactly are those arrays?  They look like lists containing objects named `one.csv` etc.  If they are numpy arrays containing strings, display that correctly.  Consider using python lists and set objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

```
result = np.setdiff1d(result, text)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
array(['five.csv', 'four.csv'], dtype='<U9')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
text = ["one.csv", "two.csv", "three.csv"]
result = ["one.csv", "two.csv", "three.csv", "four.csv", "five.csv"]

result = list(set(text).symmetric_difference(result))
print(result)
```

Prints:

```py
['five.csv', 'four.csv']
```